# repeated sum of digits big o complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Lets say for example we have the number 12345.

This sums to 15 when you add 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5, which sums to 6 when you add 1 + 5.

My question is, what would the time complexity be for a repetitive adding algorithm like this be? This process is happens until there is only a single digit left.

I know that for any given number, the # of digits is approximately ln(n). Im thinking that this means that the big o would look something like (ln(n))^k, for some k. However, I am not confident because each time you sum, the number of digits gets smaller (first summed 5 digits, then only 2).

How would I go about figuring this out?

Comment: But does that take into account the repetition? 12345 adds to 15, and then that adds to 6, so the addition process continues until you reach a single digit. So does that repetition get accounted for?

Comment: but for really large numbers, you may have to repeat the process 5 or 6 times

Comment: Oh right, that wasn't really clear. I thought they were 2 examples, not a cascade...

Comment: my apologies Ill edit to make that more clear

Comment: The order is going to be n + log10(n) + log10(log10(n)) and these subsequent passes will be hardly measurable compared to the first pass. Yes, if there are 2 first digits there could be 2 second digits, but if there are 100 first digits there can still only be 3 second digits. You would need a lot of first digits to get the second digits up to 100 and cause a proper 3rd pass, and those passes would still be comparatively insignificant.

Comment: ahh i see thank you for clarifying my confusion!

Comment: Usually, one only describes the largest effect in a series of steps, unless the sum of all the steps is significant, or the number of steps is directly driven by n, or different steps have characteristics that would make them larger for different ranges.